# In C++, given namespace-wide const float dependant on a global const float, is their initialization order guaranteed?

Tags: c++, initialization-order

If there is a pair of .h/.cpp files with something like, respectively,

```
extern const float ge;
```

and

```
const float ge = 2.2f;
```

in them, and the other .cpp file with something like

```
namespace {
const float upperLimit = 2.0f * ge;
} // namespace

bool foo(float a)
{
    return a < upperLimit;
}
```

in it, is it guaranteed that **upperLimit** is initialized after the **ge**?

I'm aware about indefinite initialization order of global objects from different translation units. I'd like to be sure if it is true for the case of mixed global and namespace-wide objects.

Comment: "something like" is pretty vague, it would be clearer if you said that that was exactly what you are asking about

Comment: There are just more than one global floats, that's it. Or do you think their exact values matter?

Comment: If the code was `const float ge = foo();` , where `foo` is not a constexpr function, then it would no longer be guaranteed to be initialized before `upperLimit`. There are many other possibilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `ge` is guaranteed to be initialized before `upperLimit` but this is nothing to do with namespaces.  The case would be the same if you didn't have the namespace. Namespaces have no effect on initialization order.

The code `const float ge = 2.2f;` is part of [constant initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization), which is part of *static initialization*,  because it is a variable with static storage duration being initialized by a constant expression.

However, in the code `const float upperLimit = 2.0f * ge;`,  the initializer is NOT a constant expression because the value of `ge` is not known.  So it is not static initialization (and therefore falls under *dynamic initialization*).

All static initialization strongly happens before dynamic initialization (C++17 [basic.start.static]/2) so the code is correct.

Comment: As far as I know float initialization cannot be static because float representation is platform-depenent so it must be initialized dynamically, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @VictorChe I linked to the cppreference page already. Floating point constants are constant expressions, [see here also](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression)

Comment: Thank you so much.